# Reference cycle when using funcarg factory in Py.Test

Tags: python, pytest

Consider the following dummy `Resource` class:

```
import pytest


class Resource:

    def __init__(self, param):
        self.param = param
        print "\nResource created", self.param, self

    def __del__(self):
        print "Resource deleted", self.param, self
```

It emulates some resource I would like to create before every testcase and fully deinitialize after the testcase. Using old-style funcargs, I write a test like

```
def pytest_funcarg__resource_fa(request):
    res = Resource(request.param)
    return res

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    metafunc.parametrize("resource_fa", [1, 2], indirect=True)

def test_funcarg_resource(resource_fa):
    print "Testcase: resource", resource_fa.param
```

When I run `py.test -s -v`, I get the following output:

```
============================================ test session starts =============================================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.3 -- pytest-2.3.3 -- /usr/bin/python
plugins: cov
collected 2 items 

test_factory.py:48: test_funcarg_resource[1] 
Resource created 1 <test_factory.Resource instance at 0x292cab8>
Testcase: resource 1
PASSED
test_factory.py:48: test_funcarg_resource[2] 
Resource created 2 <test_factory.Resource instance at 0x292cfc8>
Testcase: resource 2
PASSED

========================================== 2 passed in 0.01 seconds ==========================================
```

As you can see, the `__del__` of both Resources never got called. The same behavior is observed if I use new-style fixtures:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function", params=[1, 2])
def resource_fx(request):
    res = Resource(request.param)
    return res

def test_fixture_resource(resource_fx):
    print "Testcase: resource", resource_fx.param
```

Of course, I could add a custom finalizer and forcefully deinitialize whatever requires deinitializing inside the Resource, but this strikes me as a bit redundant — outside the testing, the `__del__` is enough to ensure the internals of the Resource get released properly, and I do not see why `Py.Test` needs to hold any references to `res` when the testcase if finished. Is it the expected behavior of `Py.Test`, or should I file a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's not a good idea to rely on `__del__` finalization because it is triggered by Garbage Collection cycles (which appear differently depending on Python implementation).  With pytest, you usually call `request.addfinalizer(resource.finalize)` from your resource/funcarg factory to have your finalizer function called appropriately.  pytest then guarantees finalization independent from GC details.

Comment: As far as I understand from Python documentation, GC is optional, and the main way to manage objects' lifetime is reference counting, which makes the use of ``__del__`` legitimate. I still do not quite get why ``Py.Test`` needs to hold references to ``Resource`` after the testcase is finished, but if you are saying that it is not a bug, I will accept that (and use some sort of test-only ``finalize()`` method in ``Resource``).

Comment: It's a valid point that pytest probably shouldn't keep a reference to the resource. Feel free to open a bug report about it.  Still, the documented and supported method of finalization is calling "request.addfinalizer" -- this also works on PyPy and Jython (which don't have a reference counting GC).  The Python docs are clear on that one shouldn't rely on ``__del__`` timing (also for file objects etc.).